# Remove object from nested array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I got this user schema

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  groups: [
    {
      groupName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      groupMembers: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "GroupMember" }],
    },
  ],
});
```

And I want to delete a group from the ‘groups’ array based on given ‘userId’ and ‘groupId’, my attempt (with express and mongoose):

```
router.delete(  
  "/:userId/:groupId",
  catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
    const { userId, groupId } = req.params;
    const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
      userId,
      { $pull: { "groups.$._id": groupId } },
      { new: true }
    );
    res.send({ updatedUser });
  })
);
```

The response of the request: I get an error: “The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.”

**Edit:**
After I delete a group I need to remove all the group members in the `groupMembers` array.
`User` collection structure example:

```
{
"_id" : "111",
"email" : "michael@gmail.com",
"username" : "michael098",
"groups" : [
    {
        "_id" : "222"
        "groupName" : "family",
        "groupMembers" : [
            {
                "_id" : "333"
                "name" : "Liam"
            },
            {
                "_id" : "444"
                "name" : "Noah"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id" : "555"
        "groupName" : "friends",
        "groupMembers" : [
            {
                "_id" : "666"
                "name" : "Oliver"
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Inside every group there is group members and I have a collection for the group members that I ref in the UserSchema : `groupMembers: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "GroupMember" }]`
`GroupMember` collection structure example:

```
{
    {
        "_id" : "333"
        "name" : "Liam"
    },
    {
         "_id" : "444"
         "name" : "Noah"
    },
    {
         "_id" : "666"
         "name" : "Oliver"
    }
 }
```

For example when I get the params of userId="111" and groupId="222" I will delete the whole 'family' group and the whole group members in the `groupMembers` array (Liam and Noah) from the `GroupMember` collection.

`GroupMember` collection after deleting the group with _id="222":

```
 {
        {
             "_id" : "666"
             "name" : "Oliver"
        }
  }
```

Comment: Where is `userId` in the schema?

Comment: `userId` is the user's _id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming an actual doc might look like this (using strings instead of `ObjectId` to keep the example tighter):

```
    {_id:1, groups: [ { type: "ID1", ref: "XX" }, { type: "ID2", ref: "G1" }, { type: \
"ID3", ref: "G2" } ] }
```

then this update will remove the subdoc in the `groups` array where `_id = 1` and `type = ID2`:

```
db.foo.update({_id:1},  
              { $pull: { groups: { type: "ID2" } }}
             );
```

Comment: Thank you it's working. Now I have another problem- I want to remove all of the `groupMembers` that are in the `group` I just removed, what is the proper way doing that?

Comment: Could you add a little more detail about what you seek?   Like a before and after document?

Comment: I edited my question. hope this is more understandable now.

Comment: `$pull` will remove the entire subdoc of `_id 222` from the `groups` array.   Do mean you want to go to a different collection and delete a group `_id` of `222`?   Edit your question to show what you want the resulting doc to look like.

Comment: Edited again, basically after I remove a group, I need to remove all the group members in this group from the 'groupMembers' collection.

Comment: That's a separate instruction, e.g. `db.groupMembers.remove({_id: 222})`

Comment: Can you please help me with another problem I'm facing with the same document? I just publish new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70039406/query-an-array-of-nested-documents