# Query an array of nested documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I got this document:

```
{
"_id" : "111",
"email" : "michael@gmail.com",
"username" : "michael098",
"groups" : [
    {
        "_id" : "222"
        "groupName" : "family",
        "groupMembers" : [
            {
                "_id" : "333"
                "name" : "Liam"
            },
            {
                "_id" : "444"
                "name" : "Noah"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id" : "555"
        "groupName" : "friends",
        "groupMembers" : [
            {
                "_id" : "666"
                "name" : "Oliver"
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to delete 1 group member by _id, for example if I get `userId="111"`, `groupId="222"` and `groupMemberId="444"` the group member with `_id="444"` will delete.

Example of the document after this delete request:

```
{
"_id" : "111",
"email" : "michael@gmail.com",
"username" : "michael098",
"groups" : [
    {
        "_id" : "222"
        "groupName" : "family",
        "groupMembers" : [
            {
                "_id" : "333"
                "name" : "Liam"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id" : "555"
        "groupName" : "friends",
        "groupMembers" : [
            {
                "_id" : "666"
                "name" : "Oliver"
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My attempt (with express and mongoose):

```
router.delete(
  "/:userId/:groupId/:groupMemberId",
  catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
    const { userId, groupId, groupMemberId } = req.params;
    const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
      userId,
      { $pull: { "groups.$.groupMembers": { _id: groupMemberId } } },
      { new: true }
    );
    res.send({ updatedUser });
  })
);
```

The response from this request: I get an error: “The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.”

Comment: The sample document contains invalid JSON and you refer to a `userId` key that is not present. Those issues make it difficult to answer the question without making several assumptions. Could you post a valid document with all the required fields?

Comment: `userId` is the _id for the user, for example in this document the `userId` is "111", this is not a new field this is the _id field, I refer it as a `userId` so it can be understandable.

Comment: The [all positional](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) operator lets you pull multiple objects from a nested array. Does this [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wENQGXb9zCJ) do what you want?